# text() not returning the text inside the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I have a component as bellow

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={toggleRecovery}>
    <PasswordText small name="passText" bold center>
         {recovery ? 'Back to login' : 'Forgot password ?'}
    </PasswordText>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

And I have written a test to check whether the text is changing with the value of the recovery as bellow

```
test('should Back to login if recovery is true', () => {
      const wrapper = shallow(<Login {...props} />)
      const value = wrapper.find('[name="passText"]')
      expect(value.length).toBe(1)
      wrapper.setState({ recovery: true })
      expect(value.text()).toEqual('Back to login')
    })
```

But I am getting an error for the test as bellow

```
expect(received).toEqual(expected)

    Expected value to equal:
      "Forgot password ?"
    Received:
      "<Styled(Styled(_default)) />"
```

Why is that I am not getting the text as the expected value and how can I resolve this issue.

Comment: Please, provide the entire component and the entire test. It's unknown how wrapper was assigned. The question doesn't even mention if Enzyme was used.

Comment: that is the component . expect(value.length).toBe(1)  . This line is pass by the test  and it is failed  in this line  expect(value.text()).toEqual('Back to login')

Comment: i am using shallow method instead of the mount is that is the issue

Comment: I see. This explains what's wrong but not how it should be fixed. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . It's required by SO rules.